# Exit C program upon entering "###"

Tags: c

I'm a beginner at C programming.

I want to exit program, when I input `###`.

```
if(char ch1 = "###")
    return 0;
```

I tried it, but that does not work.

Answer (score 1):

You need `strcmp()` for comparing strings in c, like this

```
char input[100];

if ((scanf("%99s", input) != 1) || (strcmp(input, "###") == 0))
    return 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(char ch1 = "###")
```

doesn't make sense as you are declaring a `char` and trying to initialize it with a string literal, a `char*`. Use

```
char str[4];                //Declare the array to hold 3 chars +1 for '\0'
scanf("%3s", str);          //Scan a maximum of 3 characters, +1 for the '\0'

if(strcmp(str, "###") == 0) //If str is equal to "###"
    return 0;               //End the function
```

You can't compare two strings using `==`. It will compare pointers and not the actual content. So use `strcmp` (you need to include `string.h`) as shown in the above code snippet.